# Why chef cant find a template file when run through Vagrant?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am running Vagrant 1.4.2 to run an Ubuntu 13.10 box provisioned with Chef. For some reason the template file is not found and the run fails with the following error :

```
[2014-01-07T17:25:28+00:00] ERROR: template[/etc/init/verifier-tornado.conf] (transmit::default line 48) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound: Cookbook 'transmit' (0.1.0) does not contain a file at any of these locations:
  templates/ubuntu-13.10/upstart.config.erb
  templates/ubuntu/upstart.config.erb
  templates/default/upstart.config.erb

This cookbook _does_ contain: ['/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/transmit/templates/default/upstart.conf.erb']

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/init/verifier-tornado.conf]'
================================================================================
```

The template file is part of the my custom recipe and the cookbook paths are provisioned in Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.define "web" do |web|
  web.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
   chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
   chef.roles_path = "roles"     
   chef.log_level = :debug
   chef.add_role "web"
  end
end
```

Full log of the run is available here : http://pastebin.com/fLNRukDr

Comment: Because he looks for `upstart.config.erb` and you have `upstart.conf.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output of the Chef client run, you have an incorrectly named template. You are looking for a template named `upstart.config.erb`, but your template is actually named `upstart.conf.erb` (note config vs conf).

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you! Silly naming error got me to waste at least a couple of hours :)